# Query.js Not Working Properly in Hyperledger Fabric FABCAR

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I trying to execute the fabcar sample in hyperledger fabric user1 is successfully getting loaded from persistence

Getting error while executing query.js what causing this issue

Below I have detailed log and also attached the same in screenshot for clear picture.

```
    Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server
        at new createStatusError (/home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15

root@arun-Virtual-Machine:/home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar# node query.js
Store path:/home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server
    at new createStatusError (/home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
Query has completed, checking results
error from query =  { Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server
    at new createStatusError (/home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/arun/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
  code: 14,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'Trying to connect an http1.x server' }
```

[image]

Comment: not sure how hyperledger operates but given the GRPC errors you seem to connect to the wrong port - you need a http/2 endpoint for grpc to work. This might also happen if you run your own reverse proxy in front of the endpoints.

Comment: This is a default sample app taken from Hyperledger nothing changed, the initial other 2 scripts executed successfully